# How to extend a list continuously with a function in python?

Tags: python, list, function, repeat

as the title says I have the problem that I can't do a function, where the list is expanding continuously to some value. I need this for a bigger program I'm writing.

Here are two examples that don't work.
first one:

```
from random import *
import time

A = []

def list_expander(A):
    A = A + [randint(-5,5)]
    print (A)

while True:
    list_expander(A)
    time.sleep(2)
```

and second one:

```
from random import *
import time


def list_expander():
    A = []
    A = A + [randint(-5,5)]
    print (A)

while True:
    list_expander()
    time.sleep(2)
```

thank you for your help!

Comment: your `list_expander` function doesn't do anything, it creates a new list and then discards it as soon as the function terminates. In any case, you should use `.append` here. That is what it is for.

Comment: list_expander won't extend the list, it reinitializes A it every time it's called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To modify an immutable item (for example a `list`), you can use its mutating methods (`.append()` in this case). So in your first example if you replace `A = A + [randint(-5,5)]` with `A.append(randint(-5, 5))`, you should get what you want. Your first example does not work because the function creates a "new" `A` every time you call it, it does not "change" the outside list `A`. The second one obviously won't work either because of the same reason, and also the fact that it reinitialises `A` with an empty list every time it's called (`A = []`).

All in all, I would rewrite your code as:

```
from random import randint
from time import sleep

A = []

def list_expander(A):
    A.append(randint(-5,5))
    print(A) # are you sure you need this?

while True:
    list_expander(A)
    time.sleep(2)
```

You can read [How do I pass a variable by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference) to better understand why your first example doesn't change the list `A`.

Answer (score 1):

```
from random import *
import time
def list_expander(A):
    A.append(randint(-5,5))
    print (A)
    return A
A=[]
while True:
    A=list_expander(A)
    time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: I think it's best if `list_expander()` takes the list as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you want to keep appending to the list, so you will have to return it so that you can append to it (extend) again next iteration.

```
from random import *
import time

def list_expander(A):
    A.append(randint(-5,5))
    print (A)

A = []
while True:
    list_expander(A)
    time.sleep(2)
    x+=1
```

This code will print

```
[1]
[1, -5]
[1, -5, 4]
[1, -5, 4, 5]
[1, -5, 4, 5, 2]
```

Another approach you can take is to have the list as a global variable but keep in mind it's bard practice.

Comment: I don't think there is any need to `return` the list, one can simply repeatedly call `list_expander(a)` and the list will be expanded. Also, you have a `x+=1` which does not seem to be doing anything?